# Run protractor through angular-cli without internet

Tags: webdriver, protractor, angular-cli

I need to run angular-cli e2e tests (ng e2e) on an offline development system (client restriction). However, an error occurs when Protractor tries to download chromedriver because of the connectivity issue. To manually copy the required files, I ran the command on an online system and then transferred the downloaded files from protractor node_module folder (protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_2.33 and a few other folders) to the offline system. The tests ran successfully a few times. However, the same error started again that the 'ng e2e' command causes to run webdriver-manager update although the driver file is there.

Below error appears on the console:
Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com:443

Is there an option to turn off 'webdriver-manager update' and use a local copy of the required files?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I found a solution and posted answer to a similar question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44661656)

Answer (score 1):

There is a flag that you can add to your ng command

```js
ng e2e --webdriver-update=false
```